# Who owns a dog purchased by one person and registered with the Kennel Club by another?

Tags: united-kingdom, scotland, pets

If Bob purchases a dog with his own money, and his wife Alice, with his permission, registers the dog with the Kennel Club, who owns the dog?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Law Stacks Exchange! Unfortunately, your original question was asking for specific legal advice, which we cannot provide here. I edited it into a form that should be okay; unfortunately, I had to remove most of your question, but it's much less likely that your question will be closed now.

Comment: One question would be whether the dog became marital property when purchased.  If so then a second question would be, can one spouse sell the dog without the consent of the other?

Comment: Why would you think that registering an animal confers ownership?  Regardless, marital property will be more complicated than this.

Answer (score 2):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

It doesn't matter who paid for it, and it doesn't matter who registered it. What matters is who entered into the contract to purchase it. If you pretend for a moment that the dog was collected from the seller without paying, who would the seller be entitled to sue for the money?

To work that out you need to look at what happened when the parties were negotiating for the purchase. Who, out of Bob and Alice, either made an offer which was accepted by the seller, or accepted an offer which was made by the seller? That will usually be the contracting party. However, it is possible for a person A to be acting as an agent for person B such that when A enters into a contract with a third party, they do so on behalf of B. For that to be the case, there would need to have been an agency agreement (which can be verbal) between A and B prior to the contract being entered into.

On the face of it in the scenario you describe, and without any other complicating factors, it sounds like Bob owns the dog.

Comment: But Bob and Alice are married.  From some cursory reading, it seems like it may be that even if Bob is the one who entered into the contract, that as soon as the contract was completed, the dog became the joint marital property of Alice and Bob.

Comment: @NateEldredge You are referring to the concept of matrimonial property. That simply means all property acquired by either spouse during the marriage (as opposed to non-matrimonial property which is property acquired by a spouse before the marriage). This distinction only becomes relevant in divorce proceedings when the Court is deciding how to divide assets. It doesn't affect legal ownership prior to a divorce settlement. E.g. if I buy a car in my name while married, it's still my car. But if I get divorced, my spouse may be able to claim a share of it from me.

Answer (score 1):

### [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

In Germany, dog taxes are common in almost all towns. For those, you have to register your dogs with the government and most likely gain insurance. The owner is, who is signed up as owner in the dog tax records.